# How to Move backup files from one server to another in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I need to refresh our prodution databases to another Client server on daily basis.

Requirement: I need to move .bak files from  Server a to Server b on timely basis.

We dont have any Network Drive between these servers.

Is there any way to move these files using Sql Server..

Dont have BIDS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options.  As long as it is enabled T-SQL offers the `xp_cmdshell` to execute dos commands.  With that, you can copy files as long as there is a valid windows path to both locations (and permissions are set appropriately, of course) or invoke a scriptable FTP client.  Of course, I have to point out that `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default for good reason, and enabling can be a major reduction in security.  I have used it many times to do almost what you are describing, but you must fully think through the security ramifications.

If you are moving this over a network, you may want to use compression as well.  You can of course do this with something like WinZip or 7-Zip, but many 3rd party SQL backup programs like [Red Gate's SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/) have built in compression.

Finally, you may consider doing this from outside of SQL proper, such as through Powershell which more gracefully handles file manipulations and can work with SQL Server through SMO.

Comment: Actually I am new to Sql Server, Is there any direct way to move these files using Sql scripts rather then using DOS program and all.

Comment: Not in TSQL.  TSQL is a query language first and foremost, though it has things like xp_cmdshell bolted on to provide flexibility.  SSIS has options to do it, but even SSIS will be invoking OS commands behind the scenes.  When I started (before Powershell existed) I frequently used xp_cmdshell to do what you are describing.  Now, I would recommend using Powershell and Task Scheduler if you need it scheduled unless there is some really compelling reason to do it inside of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robocopy

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/67f5aa61-759b-4c6a-9200-49ca92378066

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html